# How to give UIPopOver kind of functionality with simple UIVIew

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uislider

I want to make a UIView which should get displayed above the slider thumb and should show the value of slider. I don't want to use the PopOver as it's not looking good but the artwork i have.

Please share your views on this. I don't have to care about the apple policies as this application would not go through apple's code review. This is only for the internal survey purpose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Find a demo here, using UILabel and animation(though the class name is popover..but actually not using popover--), you can go through the source code, it's very simple, hope it can help.

Original link here:
[UILabel over slider](http://code4app.net/ios/PopView-With-Slider/4fa8f7f506f6e7d17e000000)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  mSlider = [[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 50)];
  mSlider.minimumValue = 0;
  mSlider.maximumValue = 1000;
  mSlider.value = 0;
  [mSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(updateValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

  popView = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(mSlider.frame.origin.x, mSlider.frame.origin.y-20, 70, 20)];
  [popView setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
  [popView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [popView setAlpha:0.f];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  [self.window addSubview:mSlider];
  [self.window addSubview:popView];
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (void)updateValue:(id)slider
{
  UIImageView *imageView = [mSlider.subviews objectAtIndex:2];

  CGRect theRect = [self.window convertRect:imageView.frame fromView:imageView.superview];

  [popView setFrame:CGRectMake(theRect.origin.x-22, theRect.origin.y-30, popView.frame.size.width, popView.frame.size.height)];

  NSInteger v = mSlider.value+0.5;
  [popView setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",v]];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5  
                 animations:^{  
                     [popView setAlpha:1.f];
                 }  
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){  
                     // do someting when animation finished 
                 }];

  [timer invalidate];
  timer = nil;
  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(disPopView) 
                                       userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)disPopView
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5  
                 animations:^{  
                     [popView setAlpha:0.f];
                 }  
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){  
                     //do someting when animation finished   
                 }];

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use UIAnimation to animate the view to the position you want it. Detect touches outside of your view to dismiss it.

Comment: CAn you explain a little bit more. I am kind of new to this and have never played a lot with UI's. PLease share some tutorials or links which will help me do this.